# How does the Git tracking work ? How it tracks the files present in the sub-folders?

Tags: git, github

I had my Folder Structure like the following and my `folder2->Sub-Folder` files were not being tracked by the git.

Previous Folder Structure.

```
project Folder
│   
|The .git file is in this Project Folder
|└───folder1
|    |
|    | Files
|    | The Files in this Folder get Tracked
|    |----------
|
|
|
|
|----folder2
     |
     |------Sub-Folder
                |
                |The Files is this Sub-Folder do not get tracked
                |
                |--------
```

I changed my Folder Structure, removing the sub-folder and placing the files one-way up (into the `folder2`) and they were tracked.

Updated File Structure

```
project Folder
│   
|The .git file is in this Project Folder
|└───folder1
|    |
|    | Files
|    | The Files in this Folder get Tracked
|    |----------
|
|
|
|
|----folder2
|     |Moved the child files into this Parent Folder
|     |Files
|     |These Files now get tracked
|     |----------
|    
|
```

Why is `Git` tracking the files now when I moved the files from the sub-folder to the parent folder.
Also, there is only 1 `.git` folder in the whole project folder and it is in the Project Folder, structure ->

```
project Folder
|
|.git Folder
|folder 1
|folder 2
|----------------
```

Comment: In a nutshell, Git tracks all objects within the directory that contains the `.git` directory (also referred to as project root) and all subdirectories recursively. Git only track objects/files, not directories so it will ignore all empty directories.

Comment: Even if the Directory itself do not contain any files but sub-folders that do have files ?  Git will not track them then, right ?

Comment: No Git will track them as it has an index that keeps a track of what's the folder structure looks like for files. This might help clarify how git store data and run its diff and conflicts checking. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/version-control-with/9780596158187/ch04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *track* has many different meanings in Git: there are *tracked vs untracked files*, the `git branch` command has a `--track` option, and there are things that Git calls *remote-tracking branch names*.  So it's important to be careful with the word.  It looks like you are asking about files: what makes one file *tracked* and some other file *untracked?*

#### What makes a file tracked

This has a simple and direct answer, but it requires talking about Git's *index*.  A file is *tracked* if and only if it is in Git's index *right now*.

To see the (raw) contents of the index, use:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

Note that this may produce thousands of lines of output (and is not normally paged), and its output is not intended for human consumption.  This command is meant for building more useful *other* commands.  That is, it is what Git calls a *plumbing command*.  (Other plumbing commands include `git rev-parse`, `git diff-tree`, and `git for-each-ref`.  All of them *can* be used by humans, but they tend to produce either very small results that need assembling into something useful, or very long output that needs filtering, so that it becomes useful.)

#### More about Git's index

Git's index is a central internal data structure that makes Git work.  It contains a lot of information, and during a conflicted merge, it gets expanded to contain up to three times as much information.  For *human* purposes, however, we can describe the index fairly simply: it contains your *proposed next commit*, or more precisely, the *snapshot* you intend to put into your proposed next commit.

To understand this properly, you need to know that each commit has two parts.  One part of any commit is its *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  Git generates this metadata at the time you make the commit.  It includes items like your name and email address, for instance.  We'll ignore this metadata here and concentrate on the second part of a commit: each commit also contains a *full snapshot of every file that Git knows about*.

For Git to know about a file, that file's name must appear in Git's index.  The *content* for that file is also in Git's index (but in the form of a *blob hash ID*, which is the second number in the `git ls-files --stage` output).

When you first *check out* some commit—with `git checkout` or, in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`—Git *copies*<sup>1</sup> all the files from the commit to Git's index.  This fills in the index so that it matches the commit you have checked out.  Thus, at this point in time, the files that are in the index match the files that are in the commit.  Git also extracts those same files, turning them into a more useful form to you, and puts *those* copies in your working tree.

This means *all three copies* of each of these known-about files *match*.  The current-commit copy matches the index copy and the index copy matches the working tree copy.  The `git status` command will say *nothing* about this file *because* all three copies match.

If you change a working tree file, now the current-commit and index copy still match, but they no longer match the working-tree copy.  So `git status` will say that this file is *not staged for commit*.

If you run `git add` on a file, Git will kick out any existing index copy and put in a new copy, made by compressing the working tree copy down into the internal Git format.  Now the index and working-tree copies match, but probably the index copy no longer matches the current-commit copy.  So `git status` will say that this file *is* `staged for commit`.

In other words, for `git status`, the phrase `staged for commit` means *index copy does not match current-commit copy*.  The phrase `not staged for commit` means *index copy does not match working-tree copy*.  It's possible to make all three copies different: change the working tree copy, use `git add`, and then make a *second* change to the working tree copy.  Now the file is both staged and not-staged!

To *remove* a file from Git's index, you can use `git rm`.  This removes the file from Git's index **and** removes it from your working tree.  This has no effect on any existing commit, but means that the *next* commit you make will *omit* the file.

**Note that any changes you make in your working tree affect only your working tree.**  Adding files there, or removing files from there, has no effect on Git's index—*until*, that is, you run `git add`.  The `git add` command can be thought of as meaning: *Hey Git, make some index files match up with the working tree versions!*  If you have updated them, Git has to kick out the old copies and put in new ones.  Now your proposed next commit is updated.  If you have *removed* them, Git has to kick out the old copies—so now they're gone from the proposed next commit.  If you have added *new* files, Git has to copy them into the index, so now they're in the proposed new commit as *new* files.

That's pretty much it.  This means that, aside from the conflicted merge case, you can think of the index as holding your proposed *next* commit snapshot.

---

Files in a Git commit are stored in a compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  Files in Git's index are pre-compressed, and pre-de-duplicated.  So the "copy" in the index is already de-duplicated against any existing copy in any existing commit.  These copies therefore take no space.  It's not all that important to know this, but it's useful if someone objects to all these extra copies lying around.  There's really only *one* copy—except for the working tree copies, which are expanded out, and *not* de-duplicated: *those* are the ones "wasting space".  But you need those for your other programs to work!

---

#### "Ignored" files

Because your working tree is just an ordinary everyday folder—unlike Git's commits and index, which are special database-y things that only Git itself can work with—you can create, destroy, and/or change files here whenever you like.  Git won't care, or even *know*, that you did this: Git is going to build the next commit from Git's *index*, not from your working tree.

But before you make the next commit, you probably would like to know what's *different* in that next commit.  So `git status` will *scan* Git's index, and *scan* your working tree, and tell you what's *different*.  Those are the files that are `not staged for commit`—or, if they're *new*, are *untracked files*.

This—the complaints that various files are untracked—is a problem, though.  Because many of the systems we use with Git create *many* untracked files in your working tree, we want to have a way to make Git *shut up* about some of these untracked files.  We do this by listing particular file names and/or file patterns in one particular file, named `.gitignore`.

You can have one `.gitignore` in each folder in your working tree, or you can use one master `.gitignore` at the top level, or you can have a mix of both schemes.  There's no particular reason to prefer one or another in general, although in some specific cases, there *is* a reason to prefer one or another.  This part is up to you.  But it's important to realize that `.gitignore` is the *wrong name* for what this does.  Listing a file in `.gitignore` *does not make Git ignore the file*.  If the file is *tracked*, listing that file in `.gitignore` does *nothing at all*.

If a file is *untracked*, though, listing that file's name in `.gitignore` does something very useful: it makes Git *shut up* about the file.  Instead of `git status` whining that `worktree.o` is untracked, and `ws.o` is untracked, and `zlib.o` is untracked, and so on, we say to Git: *Any `.o` file that's untracked, please don't complain, that's perfectly normal.*  And now if `git status` says that `xyz.h` is untracked, that's no longer lost in the noise about the 500 untracked files that are *supposed* to be untracked: now we can notice and `git add xyz.h`.

The `.gitignore` entry has more purposes than this, but that's the first one: `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-untracked-files-because-they-are-supposed-to-be-untracked`.  Note, though that we can use `git add` very conveniently with `git add .` or `git add *` or `git add --all`, and now we introduce the *second* meaning for listing an untracked file in `.gitignore`: it tells Git *don't **add** the file either*.

So instead of `.gitignore`, we might call this `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-file-names-if-they-are-untracked-and-do-not-add-them-either-with-en-masse-add-operations`.  That would be much more precise and accurate than `.gitignore`.  But it would also be too hard to use / too easy to get wrong, so `.gitignore` it is.

#### Summary so far

An *untracked* file is one that is not in Git's index *right now:*

- To put it into Git's index, use `git add`.  If you `git add somefile` and it's listed in `.gitignore`, Git will tell you that it's not adding the file because of the `.gitignore` entry.  Otherwise Git will add it.
- If there is a file that *is* in Git's index, that should not be, use `git rm` to remove it.  Note that this will also remove the working tree copy.

To remove a file from Git's index without removing the working tree copy, use `git rm --cached`.  Note that if the file exists in some existing commit(s), it will still be in those existing commits!  You cannot remove a file from a *repository*, only from *future commits*.  The files in your working tree are *not in the repository* (they are just copies).

#### Back to your original question

You asked why some files were untracked.  The answer is now obvious: they were not in Git's index.

If you tried to put them *into* Git's index, using `git add`, they won't *go into* Git's index if they are *ignored* as well.  If you used an en-masse `git add` operation such as `git add .`, this would happen silently; if you listed them out one by one, it would happen with a complaint message.  And, depending on what is in the various ignore files, an entire sub-folder could be en-masse ignored.  So, moving them around might change whether they get ignored.

Without further details about your particular situation, this is all we can tell you.